# How do I make sure my Profile information is imported every time, using React Native and AWS?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I have a RN/Expo app. The user can sign in and push the drawer (hamburger) button, and see their profile information. This info is pulled from an AWS server, but it is really hit or miss as to whether or not the information renders/is displayed. I would like it to display all the time, but that never seems to be a guarantee.

Below is my code:

```
export function DrawerContent (props){

const [ firstName, getFirstName ] = useState('')

useEffect(() =>{
    (async()=>{
    
        const displayName = async () =>{
            const real_response = await client_instance.get_user_info() //server function that calls user's info from the AWS server
                getFirstName(
                    <Text style = {styles.title}> 
                    {real_response.first_name} {real_response.last_name}
                    </Text>
                ) 
            }
displayName()

}
        )
       },
      [],
    )
```

...
//Inside the return statement on the drawer, where it should be rendered on opening

```
<View style = {{marginLeft: width*0.021, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
    <Title style = {styles.title}>{firstName}</Title>   
</View>
```

EDIT

```
    //This is the final form 
const displayName = async () =>{
        const real_response = client_instance.get_user_info().then(response=>{
            
            getFirstName(
                <Text style = {styles.title}> 
                {response.first_name} {response.last_name}
                </Text>
            )
        }
        )
            console.log('response is here', real_response)
    }
```

Edit for Photos:

```
    const [ imageData, getImageData ] = useState(null)
        
        const displayPhoto = async () => {          
        const real_response = client_instance.download_profile_photo().then(response=>{

getImageData(
        response.raw_data
    )  
    console.log('photo is here=>',response )            
      }         
     )     
    }
        
        displayPhoto()
        
    <View>
        {imageData && <Avatar.Image source={{uri:`data:image/jpg;base64,${imageData}`}}/>}
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While some of these answers helped, the thing that truly fixed this issue was caching the values after the user initially signs in and storing them for future use. Additionally, in case the initial response returns null, the server will keep trying get the data, and won't cache until data has been received.

Here is an example:

User signs up => User signs in => Profile info populated => Data Cached

User signs up => User signs in => Profile info doesn't populate => Server checks again until data retrieved => Data cached

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve the promise returned using **then** and call the **getFirstName** method inside.

```
 client_instance.get_user_info().then(response => { // call getFirstName here });
```

Comment: I made an edit, above, is this what you meant?

Comment: Replace `{real_response.first_name} {real_response.last_name}` with `{response.data.first_name} {response.data.last_name}`

Comment: Changed the edit. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, correct. Let me know if it works

Comment: It does not. I receive the following warning from my console: 


TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.data.first_name')


I don't have 'data' defined anywhere.

Comment: Can you check what the response contains by adding a `console.log(response)` inside the then block?

Comment: The console does not appear to be logging anything

Comment: Remove the `await` in front. Leave it like this ```client_instance.get_user_info().then(response=>{
                getFirstName(
                    <Text style = {styles.title}> 
                    {response.data.first_name} {response.data.last_name}
                    </Text>
                ) 
            }
            )```

Comment: so after removing the "await" from the function, it still does not render anything to the console, however, I can see the information in the console that I am assuming the server is sending, but it just is not rendering on screen:

`{"request": "user_info_response", "content": {"phone": "1112223344", "first_name": "JOHN", "last_name": "SMITH"}}`

Comment: Ah, perfect than. Just update as follows `{response.first_name} {response.last_name}` and it should be done. Please, accept my answer :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be real_response? Based off how I have it formatted?

Comment: You need to reference the response inside the **then** block. It is important.

Comment: This appears to have done the trick, thank you.

Comment: How would this work if I was trying to import a user photo as well?

Comment: I assume you could access the photo details using `{response.photo}` for example and using an <image> tag you could display it.

Comment: i added the way the photo is being imported/rendered above. I attempted to model the same format of your previous suggestion.

Comment: the {response.photo} doesn't quite work

Comment: log the response again to check what object you are getting

Comment: I have set the function up like so: 


`const displayPhoto = async () =>{
   const photoResponse = client_instance.download_profile_photo().then(response=>{
     getUserPhoto(response.raw_data)  
        
       console.log('photo response is here =>', response)
        }
      )
  }
` 
To which I receive the response:

photo response is here => Object {
  "success": false,
  "why": "Server timed out",
}

Comment: You are having a server timeout error because of server. There is a bigger problem.

Comment: So, when I switch it back from "response.raw_data" to "response.photo_data.raw_data" the server doesn't time out, but instead sends this to the console: 

`{"request": "download_profile_photo_response", "message_id": "1633619190702", "content": {"success": false, "photo_data": null}}`

Which is weird, because I know a photo does exist

Comment: after some tinkering, I can simplify this error to:

`photo is here=> Object {
  "photo_data": null,
  "success": false,
}`

When it is formatted like:

`const displayPhoto = async () => {
      const real_response = client_instance.download_profile_photo().then(response=>{
       getImageData(response.raw_data)
      console.log('photo is here=>',response )
      }
     )
    }`

I am attempting to display it in my code by:

`<View>
     {imageData && <Avatar.Image source={{uri:`data:image/jpg;base64,${imageData}`}}/>}
</View>`

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if your function is getting called multiple times and possibly overwriting the previous value obtained by your function. Even if this isn't the case, it's good practice to only bind these server obtained information if `real_response` is not undefined. You can also remove your unused dependency array.

```
export function DrawerContent(props) {
  const [firstName, getFirstName] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    async () => {
      const displayName = async () => {
        try {
          const real_response = await client_instance.get_user_info(); //server function that calls user's info from the AWS server
          if (real_response) {
            getFirstName("");
          } else {
            console.log("Could not fetch info from server.");
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(`Error occurred fetching from server: ${err.message}`);
        }
      };
      displayName();
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: I am having problems getting anything to log to the console now. Do you think my async following the useEffect may have something to do with this?